# DocuSign - Word/Pdf/Html file send

Tags: docusignapi

I am using .net to integrate with DocuSign however I have a requirement to take a pdf/word/html file and send it via docusign but before add a few fields to the document. I believe adding the fields should be possibly from what I have read but I am unsure how to send the pdf / word / html file directly? Please note, I will not be using a template stored in DocuSign and filling in the fields.

Other question, if I do use a template, I see you can attach other documents but can I merge the template doc and my doc I am uploading into one or will it send two different files?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you want is to send a Signature Request on a Document (as opposed to on a Template) which is easy to do, you just need to make a multipart/form-data POST request.  Have you gone through the DocuSign [Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) and subsequently the **API Tools** page?  One of the tools is the [API Walkthroughs](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs), which shows 9 of the most common API use cases, and you'll see that the 4th one (the middle left square) is titled "Request Signature on Document".

That code walkthrough shows in 6 different languages how to send a signature request on a local document- not sure what stack you're using since you didn't tag a language.  You can copy the source for you're stack and fill in the variables (or mimic the code if your language is not listed) and that will request a signature on a document.

*NOTE 1*: These samples place one signature tab at location (100, 100) to just show how to use absolute positioning.  You can alternatively use relative (or anchor) positioning, see Dev Center for more info.

*NOTE 2*: Most of the code samples send a PDF and therefore use a Content-Type of `application/pdf`.  You will have to change that for your various document types.

To answer your question on if you can merge template documents with a local document(s) and send in one single request- Yes, you can use **Composite Templates** to accomplish that.